# Read date value from Bootstrap Date/Time picker in a simpler format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I am using Eonasdan's Bootstrap Date/time picker:
https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

I would like to be able to read the selected picked date in a format of my choosing which in this case is DD/MM/YYYY. However it seems to output with the day of week, month name, day, year, time and GMT offset.

I have created an example of the script here:
http://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/1649/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p><input type="text" class="datefield" placeholder="Date 1" id="date1"/></p>
        <p><input type="text" class="datefield" placeholder="Date 2" id="date2"/></p>
    </div>
</div>


$('.datefield').datetimepicker({
   format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
})

$(document).on('dp.change', '.datefield', function(e) {
  var id=$(this).attr('id');
  var theDate=e.date;

  alert(id + " / " + String(theDate));    
});
```

When you select a date I output the ID of the date text field and the date string. I am able to set the date format for how the date appears in the date text field but not when I read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('dp.change', '.datefield', function(e) {
  var id=$(this).attr('id');
  var theDate=e.date;

  alert(id + " / " + e.date.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
});
```

You can format this date anywhere

Comment: Great thanks for this. I can see now that this is part of the momentjs.